# How retrieve user info without middleware auth:api?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, laravel-5.4, laravel-passport

I'm using Password Grant Tokens for API.
I have a route /api/contact but I do not want it uses middleware auth:api, Because it public for anyone.
I want to check and retrieve user info if the accessToken correct otherwise returns null.